# How does Maven make it easy to manage Jar files?

Tags: maven-2

While reading about Maven I came across the line below.

> A very significant aspect of Maven is the use of repositories to
>   manage jar files across different projects.

But, to be frank, I completely disagree on this: Maven requires a lot of knowledge of it, a lot of time to resolve issues related to it, requires a repository, etc.

Please tell me how Maven manages Jar files. If it's the responsibility of the developer themself to specify what jars (with versions) to use, then how does Maven makes it easy to work with, or manage, Jar files?

Comment: The fact that you don't yet know how to use Maven doesn't mean it isn't useful for managing artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

Maven has a lot of benefits with respect to managing dependencies.

1. It downloads dependencies you specify from a trusted location (the
   Maven Central repository) Dependencies don't need to be stored in
   revision control, which saves space
2. It helps managing different versions of dependencies, which makes builds reliable and reproducible (specifying the same dependency in
   different projects guarantees that both projects use the *same*
   dependency)
3. It manages the inclusion of transitive dependencies for you (adding
   a dependency to your project also adds all of that dependency's
   dependencies, and their dependencies, and so on)
4. It manages the exclusion of conflicting versions of transitive
   dependencies (if two of your dependencies rely on two different
   versions of another dependency, only one version is used. You can
   specify which one)
5. It makes your projects (local and remote) available to one another
   to use as dependencies (if a module that you're developing on your
   machine depends on another module you're developing on your machine,
   you can declare that dependency, and Maven will include the built
   version of one module when building the other)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there may be 2 scenarios where the overhead of Maven (yes, there is a steep learning curve compared to e.g. Ant) pays out:

- Manage the versions of libraries in use
- Manage the resulting libraries of your development

### Manage versions of libraries

With Ant, you normally include the used libraries somewhere in a lib folder, and it depends on the good work of your architect, if the source of the libraries is known 3 or 5 years later. Maven helps managing that by providing a place for dependent libraries. There you may exactly fix the version you want to use, and the whole setup and retrieval will be done for you.

### Manage resulting libraries

If you want to share your work with others in your company, a repository of shared libraries is the best thing then to have. By using Maven, you are able to deploy new versions to that repository, and others may use them then.

Caveat: You may use [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to do the dependency management only, if that is what you want to do.